# Preparation of a mixture of coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Suppose I have a mode of light in a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$. I want to turn it into a mixed state $\rho = a|\alpha\rangle \langle \alpha | + (1-a)|\alpha^\prime\rangle \langle \alpha^\prime|$. The easiest way of doing this that I can think of is to use some kind of an amplitude/phase modulator. Let's assume that it's an amplitude modulator - a variable transmittance, $T(t)$, beamsplitter, with 2 levels of transmittance $T_1$ and $T_2$. It is obvious that $a$ from $\rho$ will be related to the duty cycle of the modulator. We can have different variants of the shape of $T(t)$:

A) $T$ changes only once from $T_1$ to $T_2$ during the period of observation (say 1 hour) right in the middle of it (at 30 minutes).

B)$T$ changes from $T_1$ to $T_2$ with constant duty cycle equal to 1/2 and with high frequency (say 1 GHz)

C)$T$ changes from $T_1$ to $T_2$ in a Bernoulli-fashion process with high frequency and time varying duty cycle, but such that the probability to get $T_1$ or $T_2$ are still 1/2.

Do I get $\rho = (|\alpha\rangle \langle \alpha | + |\alpha^\prime\rangle \langle \alpha^\prime|)/2$ in all of that cases?

I feel that this is true for B and C but not for A, however formally it's still equal probability to get $T_1$ or $T_2$ during the observation. What am I missing in this simplistic description?